# I'm trying to call a new fragment from a cursor adapter but i get resourceNotFoundException or addView not supported

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-cursoradapter

****I want to be able to call a new fragment when the user clicks on a button which is on every item in the listview but doing it gives me an exception ****

```
  @Override
    public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        final ViewHolder view_handler = new ViewHolder();

        ...
        ...


        view_handler.update_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                FragmentManager fm = frag_context.getSupportFragmentManager(); 
        AddProfFragment frag = new AddProfFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.replace(((ViewGroup) parent_view.getParent()).getId(), frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
```

Hers's how i get parent_view and frag_context

```
public ProfessorCardAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    appContext = context;
    dataSource = new ProfessorDataSource(context);
    frag_context = (FragmentActivity) context;
    this.c = c;
}

 @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // when the view will be created for first time,
        // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View retView = inflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.professors_list_item, parent, false);
        parent_view = parent;
        return retView;
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
            at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:1773)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- I tried a the following method which gives me another kind of error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView" *

  FragmentManager fm = frag_context.getSupportFragmentManager(); 
              AddProfFragment frag = new AddProfFragment();
              FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

  ```
          transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
          transaction.replace(parent_view.getId(), frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
  ```

Comment: Please update your question with your code.

Comment: The name of the resource that is being inflated into the fragment is incorrect. It should be in the form R.layout.name_of_my_xml_layout

Comment: Can we see the code in the constructor of AddProfFragment?

Comment: AddProfFragment is a fragment class. do u think i should put a constructor? sorry for any silly questions, i'm new to android

Comment: I need the line the cursor adapter is instantiate on. More specifically, I need to see how the fragment is assigned to cursor adapter (so that when newView is called, the ViewGroup parent is in fact this same fragment, which I don't think is, and is why the null reference).

Comment: This would be a lot easier for me to see more code, there just isn't enough here to connect all the dots. If you post all related code it'd be great. While fetching that, could you please post the line that is causing the exception (I'm thinking its transaction.replace(...) but not  positive). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i finally found a simple way to solve the question.. I had to pass the parent view through the contructor.. I think the code will explain this better..

From the ProfessorFragment which contains the listview, which in turn uses the custom adater, i get a reference to the parent view and the pass it into adapter's contructor

```
 new android.os.Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cursor = dataSource.getAllProfessors();
                /*Get parent view*/
                parent_view = ((ViewGroup) getView().getParent());
                adapter = new ProfessorCardAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, true, parent_view);
                professors_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Then in my cursor adapter i get the parent view like this

```
public ProfessorCardAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery, ViewGroup p_view) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    appContext = context;
    dataSource = new ProfessorDataSource(context);
    frag_context = (FragmentActivity) context;
    parent_view = p_view;
    this.c = c;
}
```

Now with this parent view i can call the new fragment without messing up the view hierarchy

```
FragmentManager fm = frag_context.getSupportFragmentManager();
UpdateProfessorFragment frag = new UpdateProfessorFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(parent_view.getId() , frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This worked fine for me.. thank you all for the support :)

Comment: Glad to hear... You should make a real / non-anonymous SO account. Great community here.

Answer (score 0):

**0xFFFFFFFF = -1**

That means that you are using invalid resource id.

Check what returns **parent_view.getParent()).getId()**

Comment: parent_view.getParent()).getId() returns -1.. I'm not sure if that's the best way to call a the new fragment from the cursor adapter.

Comment: Check, what's inside parent_view.getParent() then. If it is not right, also check parent_view itself.

Comment: i tried parent_view.getId() but i get the following error "addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView"